# Error when trying to create a Controller in .NET CORE Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, controller

I have a .NET CORE Web application created in Visual Studio 2017. It was created as a empty template.

The startup.cs has the below code

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddSingleton<IInventoryServices, InventoryServices>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
```

The program.cs is like below:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) => 
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

I tried to create a Controller. The type of the controller I selected to add was "MVC Controller with views, using Entity Framework". When trying to create, in the window i have specified the model class, and ticked for "Generate views", "Reference script libraries" and "Use layout page" which by the way are ticked by default. The text-box to specify the Layout page is left blank.

When trying to create the controller I get the below error:

> There was an error running the selected code generator: Scaffolding
>   failed to edit Startup class to register the new Context using
>   Dependency injection. Make sure there is a Startup class and a
>   Configuration property in it

Couldn't figure out why this error is happening. Is it because of DI or Entity Context issue ?

Comment: AminGolmahalle is right, follow the tutorial:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#create-a-database-context-class

Answer (score 1):

You would have to make sure that the DbContext is registered in the Startup class  **ConfigureServices()** method as well.

First Injection **IConfiguration** interface in Startup Class:

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
```

then Add Below Code To ConfigureServices Method:

```
services.AddDbContext<AppContext>(options => 
       options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

and then Add ConnectionString Address in **appsettings.json** :

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=YourDatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Just one clarification. I didn't understand the IConfiguration injection. Can i know whats the purpose of it ?

Comment: IConfiguration interface for reading config from appsettings.json according to the key. Could you overcome the problem?

Comment: learn more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: I am a newbie to Core. I dont have a appsettings,json in my project. There is a launchSettings.json in the properties section. How should I add the ConnectionString. Please advise

Comment: @sms101 For learning about concpet asp.net core please see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59701684/5576498

Comment: @sms101 if resolved your problem please accept my answer.

Comment: I have manually configured EF in core for ASPNET core projects many times. I got this error message after trying out the "Add Controller" for API (not MVC) on a new ASPNET .NET 5 project...hoping that after all these years some normalcy and robustness with regard to the "Add Controller..." tool would ensue. I'll check back next year.

Answer (score 0):

You must first configure the dependency injection of the DbContext. This tutorial explain step by step what you need to do.

[ASP.NET With Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.2#register-the-schoolcontext)

Answer (score 0):

Try Updating the packages in the projects using nuget package manager to the latest.

This solved the problem "I am using .Net 5.0" so this might work for you.