# ASP.NET Core API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

It's the first time that I have to use API in ASP.NET Core application and I have no idea about how to use it. I'm a little bit confused. Any lead, help, explanation would be appreciated please.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First learn this [link](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/core) about ASP.NET Core concepts.

Then next learn about Entity Framework Core [Learn Entity Framework Core](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/)

Then create a **todo** project for understand concepts asp core according to this [link](https://medium.com/@ThisisZone/to-do-write-to-do-app-with-asp-net-core-c02bc3ca9fa1).

Finally read this article [Creating ASP.NET Core 2.2 Application Step-by-Step](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5061469/Creating-ASP-NET-Core-2-2-Application-Step-by-Step)