# Error when configuring services - Adding Entity Framework Core to ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have created an ASP.NET Core web application. I am trying to add Entity Framework Core to my solution.

I have installed the below nugets to the project.

- "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
- "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"
- "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer"

There is a DbSet defined in the Context.

In the startup class when i try to add the Db Context, I get the following error in the for "Configuration".

> The Name Configuration does not exist in the current context.

My code is:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
}
```

I am following [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.2#register-the-schoolcontext) which doesn't say much about the configuration

Comment: Did you include the relevant `IConfiguration Configuration` property/field in the startup?

Comment: I suggest to you this link for resolve problem :https://stackoverflow.com/a/59653471/5576498

Comment: @AminGolmahalle thank you for the reply. I am a newbie to .Net Core. I dont have a  appSettings.json in the solution. There is a launchSetting.json under Properties. How should a add the ConnectionString? Should I create a new .json file in the solution for this? Please advise

Comment: @sm101 For learning about concpet asp.net core please see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59701684/5576498

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code sample is incomplete. The Configuration actually is a property of the Startup class. It is populated via constructor dependency injection.

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => 
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    }

    //...
}
```

As mentioned on the last step of the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.2#get-the-code) : the full code is available on https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/data/ef-mvc/intro/samples/cu-final